# Full search in SFDC - Should I implement an external engine?

Tags: sosl, search

We have a collection of objects created by a **third party application** (from the AppExchange). The objects are basically job openings with information stored in many fields with different data types (description, skills, experience, department, etc.)

We need to create a **search interface** to allow candidates to look for a job using any search query that they want. The search algorithm needs to look for keywords in **any field, do synonym expansion, lemmatization, etc.**

My team is proposing that we (1) implement an instance of **SOLR** in another server, (2) extract all he data from SFDC, (3) Index the info in the SOLR server and (4) create a simple API to communicate between end clients, SOLR and SFDC

I recently read that SOLR is powering SFDC search so I cannot stop feeling that we are reinventing the wheel

**Question**: Can we do this using SOSL or SOQL and avoid "creating" our own search engine?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this with a well designed approach using SOQL / SOSL as you suspected.

Creating your own search engine / extending an external search engine seems to me to be huge overkill and (no offence) sounds like the type of approach proposed by a team who are not very familiar with the Force.com platform.

First steps would be a thorough read of the Force.com SOQL and SOSL
Reference [link](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf) (against SFSE policy to link without quoting, but I can't really quote the whole guide).

Next steps then would be to read up how Visualforce and / or Lightning work so you can start preparing a POC on how your solution will work.

Good luck!

Comment: I suspect SOSL/SOQL won't do *everything* that OP needs, but computing is full of trade offs, and keeping this on platform would make much more sense and be the much simpler solution, so I'd aim for that if the search can be 'close enough' to perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I personally used Solr in a similar case, and did it exactly the same way you are describing it above. I don't know about SOSL and SOQL, and I can't comment on them. However, using Solr is a separate instance can be a great idea. First, it's not tightly coupled with any internal SFDC technology. You can maintain it on the side, without dealing with the internal implementation of SFDC. All what you need to do is make sure you always have the right API calls.

Using Solr gives you the flexibility to add more content that your users might be interested in. Imagine if your end users wanted to have access to certain documents, emails, etc. With a stand-alone Solr-based search solution, add features and content easily.

---

-SR

[Big Wisdom](http://bigwisdom.net/)